# Combining first x number of characters in column 1 of csv to all of column 2

Tags: bash, csv, awk, sed

I have been trying to figure out how to create a "unique" name for each of the entities in a CSV.  If i had the following:
input.csv

```
CustomerName,ID
businessName1,123456
businessName2Could Be longer with spaces,23456
businessName3Could use - or other special chars,234567
```

What i am trying to get to is removing the full business name and creating a "coded" (using that term lightly) name to hide full business names.

I have been trying to figure out an all in one solution.

potentialOutput.csv

```
CodedName
bus123456
bus23456
bus234567
```

I can easily use cut to get the first few letter / bytes of each line in the CSV.  That solves part 1 of my problem.  The second part is adding in the ID.  I know they all look similar if i used the first 3 characters - however the ID someone can search in a larger data warehouse that can get the rest of the information.

Getting the data cleansed to the above was some sorcery - but utilized the following commands to get there.

I am almost sure this can be done with sed / awk - just not as familiar with all the flags to get to the output i need.

Below is how i got to this point.

```
awk '{gsub(/\"/,"")};1' Custom.csv | awk '{gsub(/\(/,"")};1' | awk '{gsub(/\)/,"")};1'  > custom_RC.csv

sed '1,2 d' custom_RC.csv | sed '1 d' | awk '{gsub(/\(/,"")};1' | awk '{gsub(/\)/,"")};1' |  awk '{gsub(/\"/,"")};1' | cut -f 1,4 -d ,
```

Comment: Won't you need to create a map file, with your coded version and then the full name? Also, reduce calls to external processes like `awk '{gsub(/\"/,"");gsub(/\(/,"");gsub(/\)/,"")}'  Custom.csv > custom_RC.csv` (may need a little cleaning up.) (and `;1` not needed in this case). And can be reduced to 1 or 2 `gsub`s, using `(/srchTarg1|srchTarg2|..../,"",$0)`. Good luck.

Comment: and `sed 1,2 d | sed 1 d` , isn't that the same as `sed 1,3 d` ? But that can be done with awk, i.e. `awk -F, 'NR >=3 {next} {gsub(...)`. print $1,$4}`. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this `awk`:

```
awk -F, '{print (NR == 1 ? "CodedName" : substr($1, 1, 3) $2)}'  file.csv
```

```
CodedName
bus123456
bus23456
bus234567
```

Comment: perhaps replace `BEGIN`  with  `NR==1`

Comment: There is some more data clean up that i need to do but that worked and what i was looking for.  Thank you.